# Como fazer uma consulta com condições de tabelas diferentes

Tags: sql, query

> TABELA CADASTRO A
>        Atributos: Codigo, nome, tipo
>       TABELA NUMERO B
>        Atributos: Codigo, numero
>       TABELA PESSOA C
>        Atributos: Codigo, genero

Preciso trazer as informações nome e tipo da tabela A com os números correspondentes da tabela B filtrando pelos atributos "tipo" da tabela A e "genero" da tabela C.

Segue minha tentativa de consulta:

```
select A.NOME, B.NUMERO
from A
left join B on
A.codigo = B.codigo
where
A.tipo=B and
C.genero='Homem'
```

Comment: Onde está a ligação de "C.genero" com as tabelas A e B? A coluna "A.tipo" é uma chave estrangeira para B? Me parece que você precisa aprimorar a modelagem das tabelas. Poste mais informações sobre a regra de negócios que podemos te ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

A modelagem precisa melhorar mesmo, mas pelo que vi código é chave primaria e estrangeira. Supondo que isso seja verdade, então é necessário incluir a tabela PESSOA na consulta para poder buscar por um campo dela. Sua query poderia ficar assim:

```
SELECT c.nome, n.numero, p.genero
FROM cadastro c
LEFT JOIN numero n ON c.codigo = n.codigo
LEFT JOIN pessoa p ON c.codigo = p.codigo
WHERE c.tipo='sei la' and p.genero='Homem';
```